# How to set the repeat UILocal Notifications on the select list of Weekdays

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uilocalnotification, localnotification

I have implemented **UILocal Notification** using the following link

http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/07/31/adding-local-notifications-with-ios-4.html

And i have modified it to set the repet Notifications on each day by using

```
//To set the repeat notification
            notif.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit;
```

For exampke ex **Every day at 10.00 AM**

But my requirement is user needsto **set the notification on selected Week Days (Monday to saturDay)**

why because user may have **weekly holidays like (SaturDay and Sunday) / Friday - Sunday) / Some other days**..

on the *`week offs he shouldn't fire the notifications.`*

So we felicitate user to set the selected Working days and the notifications will set on those days only.. once user set the notifications.

***`For ex:`***

we have **list of weekday Sun, MOn, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Saturday**

on those **user selects Monday, Tuesday,WednesDay, Thursday. and set at 10Am**

*Then the notification will fire on every day 10.AM of these days.*

How to do it

Answer (score 8):

The API for UILocalNotification is very limited in this regard - you'll have to manually schedule 4 events repeating weekly on the days that the user selects.

An example of scheduling a repeat timer for monday would look like this

```
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
dateComponents.weekday = 2; // sunday = 1 ... saturday = 7
dateComponents.hour    = 10;

UILocalNotification *notification = //...
notification.repeatInterval = NSWeekCalendarUnit;
notification.fireDate       = [calendar dateFromComponents:dateComponents];
```

The day numbers can be found in the [NSDateComponents Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateComponents_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001502-BCIGCBDB)

Comment: Since NSWeekCalendarUnit is now depreciated, what's the proper way to schedule weekly repeats?

Comment: In the docs near where it shows that this is deprecated it says `Use NSCalendarUnitWeekOfMonth or NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear instead.`

Comment: I've tried both of those but neither has worked for me.

Comment: Scratch that, NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear seems to be working properly now.

Comment: @Luke Irvin: can you please post your working code here, Paul.s's answer looking fine, confused in getting that done in manually timer?